# Joomla 3 changes

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I have a joomla 3.0.3. (upgraded from 2.5). But the joomla keeps changing my html code when I save a custom html module.

I am using the JCK editor and have tried "none" editor as well but that doesn't change it. I have also switched the text filter permissions in the global settings to "no filtering"... no change ether.

### This is the code I am entering (an image and a table):

```
<p style="text-align: center;">
<img alt="En verden af skønne og skæve blomster" src="images/Content/General/skoenneogskaeveblomster.png" style="width: 428px; height: 39px;" /></p>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%;">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: top; width: 20%;">
            <strong>Nyhedsmail</strong></td>
        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: top; width: 20%;">
            <strong>Adresse</strong></td>
        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: top; width: 20%;">
            <strong>Kontakt</strong></td>
        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: top; width: 20%;">
            <strong>Bankoplysninger</strong></td>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="1" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: top; width: 20%;">
            <strong>Åbningstider</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: top; width: 20%;">
            <p>
                Gå ikke glip af tilbud og arangmenter.</p>
            <p>
                <a href="http://blomstergalleriet-viborg.dk/>Tilmeld dig vores nyhedsmail.</a></p>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: top; width: 20%;">
            <p>
                Blomster Galleriet</p>
            <p>
                Li. Sct. Mikkelsgade 19</p>
            <p>
                8800 Viborg</p>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: top; width: 20%;">
            <p>
                Tlf: 86 84 86 84</p>
            <p>
                Email: <a href="mailto:someemail?subject=Blomster%20Galleriet">someemail</a></p>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: top; width: 20%;">
            <p>
                Reg. nr: 2783</p>
            <p>
                Konto nr: 4380 1656 49</p>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: right; vertical-align: top; width: 10%;">
            <p>
                Mandag - Fredag:</p>
            <p>
                Lørdag:</p>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: top; width: 10%;">
            <p>
                9:30 - 17:30</p>
            <p>
                9:30 - 13:00</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: top; width: 20%;">
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: top; width: 20%;">
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: top; width: 20%;">
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: top; width: 20%;">
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="1" style="vertical-align: top; width: 10%; text-align: center;">
            <strong>Specielle åbningstider</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: top; width: 20%;">
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: top; width: 20%;">
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: top; width: 20%;">
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: top; width: 20%;">
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td style="text-align: right; vertical-align: top; width: 10%;">
            <p>
                Store bededag:</p>
            <p>
                Mors dag:</p>
            <p>
                Pinse dag:</p>
            <p>
                2. Pinse dag:</p>
            <p>
                Uge 29-30:</p>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: top; width: 10%;">
            <p>
                9:30 - 13:00</p>
            <p>
                7:00 - 14:00</p>
            <p>
                Lukket</p>
            <p>
                Lukket</p>
            <p>
                Ferielukket</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

*Webmaster og designer: Me*

### But when I have saved it looks like this:

```
<p>
&lt;p center;\&quot;=&quot;&quot;&gt; <img af="" alt="\&quot;En" nne="" og=""  src="\&quot;images/Content/General/skoenneogskaeveblomster.png\&quot;" ve="" verden="" /></p>
<p>
Nyhedsmail</p>
<table border="\&quot;0\&quot;" cellpadding="\&quot;0\&quot;" cellspacing="\&quot;0\&quot;" td="">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td a="" af="" dig="" glip="" href="\&quot;http://blomstergalleriet-viborg.dk/" ikke="" og="" td="" tilbud="" tilmeld="" vores="">
            <p>
                Blomster Galleriet</p>
            <p>
                Li. Sct. Mikkelsgade 19</p>
            <p>
                8800 Viborg</p>
        </td>
        <td 84="" 86="" a="" href="\&quot;mailto:someemail?subject=Blomster%20Galleriet\&quot;" td="">
            <p>
                Reg. nr: 2783</p>
            <p>
                Konto nr: 4380 1656 49</p>
        </td>
        <td -="" mandag="" td="">
            <p>
                9:30 - 17:30</p>
            <p>
                9:30 - 13:00</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td td="">
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td td="">
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="\&quot;2\&quot;" rowspan="\&quot;1\&quot;" specielle="" td="">
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td td="">
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td td="">
            <p>
                Store bededag:</p>
            <p>
                Mors dag:</p>
            <p>
                Pinse dag:</p>
            <p>
                2. Pinse dag:</p>
            <p>
                Uge 29-30:</p>
        </td>
        <td -="" 7:00="" 9:30="" p="">
            <a href="\&quot;mailto:someemail?subject=Blomster%20Galleriet\&quot;"><em>&lt;span 9px;\&quot;=&quot;&quot;&gt;Webmaster og designer: Me</em></a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

As you can see the following changes:
* Image doesn't load
* links changing
* text size changes
* table changes

I hope someone knows what to do.

Comment: Do you have the parameter filter="safehtml" set in your field editor?

Comment: sorry... where is that?

Comment: In your xml file models/forms/your_form_nanme.xml or are you using hard coded view?

Comment: ehh.. I am logging in as a super user.... editing the custom html module (in the WYSIWYG editor). The html code above is from the source view of the editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to Work now. I think it was something about the magic quotes setting on the PHP setup.

Answer (score 0):

Did you toggle the editor off (show the HTML source) when entering the HTML tags? Otherwise the editors usually assume you want to enter some text and changes the HTML tags so it's safe to show.

Or your server does some funny things on its own.